# Use the complex power series of $f(z)= \frac{2}{1+3z}$ to find the complex power series of $g(z)= \frac{1}{(1+3z)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

> Use the complex power series of $f(z)= \frac{2}{1+3z}$ to find the complex power series of $g(z)= \frac{1}{(1+3z)^2}$.

**My attempt:**

Notice that \begin{align}f(z) &= \frac{2}{1+3z}= \frac{2}{1-(-3z)} =2\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-3z)^n \end{align} with circle of convergence $|z|< \frac{1}{3}$

Now, notice that $$f'(z) = \frac{-6}{(1+3z)^2}$$
Hence we have that \begin{align}g(z) &= \frac{1}{(1+3z)^2} \\ &= -\frac{1}{6}f'(z) \\ &= -\frac{1}{6} \frac{d}{dz}\bigg[2\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-3z)^n\bigg] \\ &= -\frac{1}{3} \frac{d}{dz}\bigg[\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-3z)^n\bigg]\end{align}
Am I on the right track? This is the part that feels very risky to me, because I am not too sure we can simply assume that the series we have is term-by-term differentiable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** You are on the right track. A [power series representation of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series) $f$ can be [differentiated term-by-term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Differentiation_and_integration) to obtain a power series representation of its derivative $f'$. The interval of convergence of the differentiated series is the same as that of the original series.

Comment: So we have that $g(z) = \frac{-1}{3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg[ n (-3)^n z^{n-1}\bigg]$?

Comment: @DJS Yes, you are right.

Comment: And that simplifies to $g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n(-3z)^{n-1}$? :)

Comment: @DJS Yes, and the sum may start at $n=1$.

Comment: I noticed that now, since the first term is imply zero :). Thank you! :)